# Rails ActiveResource Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeresource

I have some ARes models (see below) that I'm trying to use associations with (which seems to be wholly undocumented and maybe not possible but I thought I'd give it a try)

So on my service side, my ActiveRecord object will render something like

```
render :xml => @group.to_xml(:include => :customers)
```

(see generated xml below)

The models Group and Customers are HABTM

On my ARes side, I'm hoping that it can see the `<customers>` xml attribute and automatically populate the `.customers` attribute of that Group object , but the has_many etc methods aren't supported (at least as far as I can tell)

So I'm wondering how ARes does it's reflection on the XML to set the attributes of an object.  In AR for instance I could create a `def customers=(customer_array)` and set it myself, but this doesn't seem to work in ARes.

One suggestion I found for an "association" is the just have a method

```
def customers
  Customer.find(:all, :conditions => {:group_id => self.id})
end
```

But this has the disadvantage that it makes a second service call to look up those customers... not cool

**I'd like my ActiveResource model to see that the customers attribute in the XML and automatically populate my model.  Anyone have any experience with this??**

```
# My Services
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customer
end

# My ActiveResource accessors
class Customer < ActiveResource::Base; end
class Group < ActiveResource::Base; end

# XML from /groups/:id?customers=true

<group>
  <domain>some.domain.com</domain>
  <id type="integer">266</id>
  <name>Some Name</name>
  <customers type="array">
    <customer>
      <active type="boolean">true</active>
      <id type="integer">1</id>
      <name>Some Name</name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
      <active type="boolean" nil="true"></active>
      <id type="integer">306</id>
      <name>Some Other Name</name>
    </customer>
  </customers>
</group>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ActiveResource does not support associations. But it doen't prevent you from setting/getting complex data to/from a ActiveResource object. Here is how I would implement it:

**Server side model**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customers
end
```

**Server side GroupsController**

```
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => @group.to_xml(:include => :customers) }
  end    
end
```

**Client side model**

```
class Customer < ActiveResource::Base
end

class Group < ActiveResource::Base
end
```

**Client side GroupsController**

```
def edit
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  if @group.load(params[:group]).save
  else
  end
end
```

**Client View: Accessing customer from Group object**

```
# access customers using attributes method. 
@group.customers.each do |customer|
  # access customer fields.
end
```

**Client side: Setting customer to Group object**

```
group.attributes['customers'] ||= [] # Initialize customer array.
group.customers << Customer.build
```